# How to add feedback when user clicks on command button?

Tags: apex, visualforce

When a user click on the button Save/Update, it does what it should but it doesn't give the user feedback that it did it. I would prefer not to refresh the page.

How to give the user feedback?

```
<apex:page standardController="Community_Yearly_Plan__c" extensions="vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr" cache="false">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbsCon" >
                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon">
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon" value="{!listGoalsCurrYear}" var="cpgs">
                      <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="cnt"/>   
                        <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                            <apex:commandlink value="Remove" action="{!removeRecord}" immediate="true">
                                <!-- Pass the row number to the controller so that we know which row to remove -->
                                <apex:param name="index" value="{!cnt}"/>
                            </apex:commandlink> 
                            <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>  

                        </apex:column>  
                        <apex:column value="{!cpgs.Year__c}" />                        
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Type</apex:facet>                             
                            <apex:inputField id="ft" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Type__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Core Current Participation</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="ccp" value="{!cpgs.Core_Current_Participation__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True'  || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   

                        <apex:column style="width:10px;">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Amount</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="fa" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Description</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="fd" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column style="width:10px;">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="ga" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount Comments</apex:facet>                            
                            <apex:inputField id="gac" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                    <apex:commandButton style="align:center;" action="{!AddRow}" value="Add Goal Setting" reRender="pbsCon" />
                    <apex:commandButton style="align:center;" action="{!SaveRecords}" value="Save/Update" reRender="pbsCon" />                    

                </apex:outputPanel>

                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon2">
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon2" value="{!listGoalsPrevYears}" var="cpgs2">

                        <apex:column value="{!cpgs2.Year__c}" />                        
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Type</apex:facet>                            
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Type__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Core Current Participation</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Core_Current_Participation__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Amount</apex:facet>                                                                                     
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Description</apex:facet>                                                                                     
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount</apex:facet>                                                                                     
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount Comments</apex:facet>                                                        
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                </apex:outputPanel>                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `apex:pagemessages` attribute.

In your controller add the `pagemessage` and then `rerender` the section.

```
ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Success');
ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
```

and on VF page include

```
<apex:pageMessages />
```

Comment: This is good but where do I put 'ApexPages.Message myMsg'? If I put it at the top of my controller when I load the page it automatically shows "success". If I put it in the save method, it doesn't show.  Also where to put "<apex:pageMessages />"?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b put `ApexPages.Message myMsg` in save method and `<apex:pageMessages />` in `apex:form` and give some id to this from and rerender this form you will get the message.